# How to select "Group" column name from another table in an SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reserved-words

Group is column in one of the table.
I am using below query. As Group is reserve keyword, getting error while executing below query:

```
select o.group as group,
 p.id as id 
from
product p left join org o on p.id=o.id
```

Could anyone guide?

Comment: Simple - just don't use reserved keywords as object names then you won't ever have this issue; `select o.group as ProductGroup,` - fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular SQL Server way:

```
select o.[group] as [group],
```

And SQL Server does also support the ANSI SQL way (perhaps some setting needed?)

```
select o."group" as "group",
```